# how to save picture using php?

Tags: php, mysql, file, save

```
<?php
$size       = filesize('H:/blog_banner.jpg');
$fp         = fopen('H:/blog_banner.jpg','rb');
$binary_pic = fread($fp,$size);
$link       = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','123456') or die('connect failed!');
$binary_pic = base64_encode($binary_pic);

mysqli_select_db($link, 'rqPro');
mysqli_query($link,"insert into tb_pic values('',$binary_pic)") or die('cant perform pic');
```

The result is:

> cant perform pic.

The picture in mysql save field is :medium blob.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use file_get_contents('tourpic.jpg') to retrieve image, if needed like u want do base64 encode and save to your mysql field. But better practice generally is saving reference in database, and file on filesystem, this will reduce your db export size and db load

Answer (score 1):

Your insert query is wrong. You don't specify which field of table it will be saved.
It should be .. INSERT INTO tb_pic(`field1`,`field2`) VALUES('',$binary_pic)

And my advice, it's not a good way to save pictures in Database. It's heavy. It's better to save it in your server / directory.
Try to look http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the image string:

```
values('','$binary_pic')
```

Also, make sure the image is small enough to fit inside a medium blob. Otherwise, it will get trimmed and you won't be able to extract it correctly

Note: if the table has more than two columns, you need to specify the ones for which the inserted data is for.